# qBCPEо with negative sigma values

Tags: percentile, gamlss

I am trying to use qbcpeo to produce lower limit than normal for a gamless bcpe object, however, some of the sigma values (sigma link is log) yields negative value so when I attempt to use qbcpeo I get the error "sigma must be positive" how can I solve this?

I tried using absolute sigma values and exp(sigma) but nothing works

Answer (score 0):

qBCPEo(p,mu,sigma,nu,tau)
gives the p quantile for BCPEo(mu, sigma, nu, tau).

The predictor for sigma can be negative,
with sigma = exp(predictor).
sigma itself cannot be negative.

If you still have problem, please give an example of the R commands
you are using.

By default

predict(   , what="sigma",  )

gives the predictor of sigma, i.e. log(sigma).

It is easies to use

mm$LLNFEF2575<-qBCPEo(0.05, mu = mm.bcpefef2575$mu,

sigma = mm.bcpefef2575$sigma,

nu = mm.bcpefef2575$nu,

tau = mm.bcpefef2575$tau,

lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)

Comment: Thank you for this, this is the gamlss obj sigma equation is:
Sigma link function:  log,
Sigma Coefficients:
(Intercept)  -3.93778    pb(log(age))  0.64825,    
this is the command I used: mm$Sfef2575 <- predict(mm.bcpefef2575, what="sigma", data=mm)   and mm$LLNFEF2575<-qBCPEo(0.05, mu = mm$Mbcpe2575, sigma = mm$Sfef2575, nu = mm$Lbcpefef2575,tau = mm$Pfef2575, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE) and the error I get is sigma must be positive

Comment: Thank you for this it is really helpful, however, now I am getting this mm$LLNFEF2575<-qBCPEo(0.05, mu = mm.bcpefef2575$mu, sigma = mm.bcpefef2575$sigma, nu = mm.bcpefef2575$nu,tau = mm.bcpefef2575$tau, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)
Error in if (nu < 0) { : argument is of length zero